# an interesting qn related to interchange iterated integration ..

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

If $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, show that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{2 h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y) d y\right) d x=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) d x .
$$

Comment: Are you perhaps missing a $\lim_{h\to0}$ sign? Also see the Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Comment: Please edit your question: if there is supposed to be a limit, add that limit sign. Also, as soon as you bother to take the time to read about the Lebesgue differentiation theorem you will get the answer (if there is, as I suspect, a limit)

Comment: @FShrike actually my qn is correct h is fixed here..

Comment: look i changed the title also..

Comment: @Kavi rama murthy sir csn you give some hint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows directly from Fubini's theorem: \begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y) \,dy \,dx &= \frac 1{2h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{x-h}^{x+h}f(y) \,dy \,dx  \\
&= \frac 1{2h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{y-h}^{y+h}f(y) \,dx \,dy\\
&=  \frac 1{2h}\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2h \cdot f(y)\,dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty  f(y)\,dy. \end{align*} Applying Fubini's theorem is justified since $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: how you change the limit ftom x-h to x+h to y-h to y+h.this was not justified..

Comment: @Shrihari Put the limits into an indicator function and then apply Fubinis theorem.

Comment: also one correction @Jack T here imit should be from -infinty to +infinity..

Comment: @Shrihari ah yes that was a typo - thanks